# AJAX - Parse JSON object returned in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I stucked a little bit in here>

My php script returns this JSON (in variable response) (encoded array with json_encode) :

```
{"1":{"id":"pvv001","tooltip":"tip1","link":"http:\/\/domain\/file1.html"},"2":{"id":"pvv002","tooltip":"tip2","link":"http:\/\/domain\/file2.html"}}
```

I hope this is valid JSON object ...

Then here is JavaScript function which should get this string and process it - load to ELEMENT "id" a content of "link".

```
function jLinks(idchapter)
{
    var url = 'ajax_loadlinks.php';
    var data = {
        idchapter : idchapter
    };
    $.post(url,data, function(response)
    {
        //$('#coursecontent').html(response);

        var obj = JSON.parse(response);
        for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i+1)
        {
            $('#'+obj[i].id).html('<a href="'+obj[i].link+'">link</a>');
        }

    });
}
```

It is not throwing any error in browser or console, but elements are not updated at  all.

I quess my parsing and accessing data is wrong somehow, but I have no idea how to debug.

Comment: Your JSON is not describing an array, it is instead describing a regular object,. So `obj` isn't going to have a `length` property, therefore your loop never runs.

Comment: try with `for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++)` in place of `for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i+1)`

Comment: json  need to be enclosed  in between`[]`

Comment: You have to fix this via PHP, make sure it is an array that is being parsed into JSON.

Comment: so, does this mean problem is with passed JSON string itself ? this is how do it (rows are fetched from DB)>
<code>
$x=0;
foreach ($rows as $row)
  {
   $x++;
   
   $link = $row['link'];
   $linkid = $row['linkid'];
   $linktooltip = $row['linktooltip'];
   
   $result[$x]['id']=$linkid;
   $result[$x]['tooltip']=$linktooltip;
   $result[$x]['link']=$link;
  }
 }
 
 $return = json_encode($result);
 
 echo $return;
</code>
sorry, i dont know how to format code he in comment ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your string is an `object` not `array`, so you need [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) method to loop over each `key` of object.

```
var obj ={
  "1": {
    "id": "pvv001",
    "tooltip": "tip1",
    "link": "http:\/\/domain\/file1.html"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": "pvv002",
    "tooltip": "tip2",
    "link": "http:\/\/domain\/file2.html"
  }
};

$.each(obj,function(i,v){
    $('#'+v.id).html('<a href="'+v.link+'">link</a>');
});
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/44g0f4s2/)**

Comment: thank you very much, this solve my problem! elemets are updated now with this $each loop.

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
 for (var prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          console.log(obj[prop].id);
          $('#'+obj[prop].id).html('<a href="'+obj[prop].link+'">link</a>');
    }
}
```